# Could not find file "...\bin\Debugdb.mdb" when trying to open an Access .mdb file

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to make a very simple application that connects to an Access 2003 database.
I built a very simple user interface with 7 labels and 7 text-box with only 2 buttons: one of them is "Save" and the other one is "Exit".

Inside my form I added the code :

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Try
    Dim saveinto As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim constr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "db.mdb"
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr)
    saveinto.Connection = conn
    saveinto.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    saveinto.CommandText = " insert into users(id,username,nid,money,mode,help,yesorno) " & " values ('" & TextBox7.Text & "' ,'" & TextBox1.Text & "' , '" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "' , '" & TextBox4.Text & "' , '" & TextBox5.Text & "' , '" & TextBox6.Text & "')"
    conn.Open()
    saveinto.ExecuteNonQuery()
    conn.Close()
    MsgBox("All Done :P ")
            Exit Sub

End Sub
```

when i press the Save Button i got that error :

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

and its the first time to see it, i thought that something wrong in my system (WinVista:) or database (build with my Access 2007 then converted to 2003) and i uninstall Access 2007 and install 2003 then rebuild new database and replace the old one with it.

When i run my app and press the Save Button i got the same error Message with

> OledbException was unhandled `Could not find file 'C:\Users\Mahmoud\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\bin\Debugdb.mdb`.

i searched here before asking my question for my problem but i couldn't find the same problem and and i tried to apply some suggestions from similar errors but nothing happened so forgive me if duplicated a question and please HELP.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `Application.StartupPath` returns

```
C:\Users\Mahmoud\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Test\Test\bin\Debug
```

and that does not have a trailing backslash (`\`), so when you append `db.mdb` to it you get a path that does not actually point to your database file. Try

```vb
... Application.StartupPath & "\db.mdb"
```

instead.

Comment: thank you sir @Gord Thompson it fix the
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll`
 error but i got : Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. and i write the insert statement in my first post can u please review it? thanks again :) –